# adding rc filter to cheap sub

Tags: filter, low-pass, sound

I bought a cheap computer Sub to repurpose it as a selfmade gaming vest. The circuit has 2 amplifiers on it, one for the normal unfiltered sound that goes to the 2 speakers, and then the output of this one is filtered and sent to a second amplifier for the subwoofer. 
The filtering is not great... I tried with a wave generator and got clear, loud sound up to 11.000 hz... I would like to add a low pass filter that has a cutoff frequency of 200Hz on the input of the second amplifier. 
I found a 1uF capacitor at home, and after googeling around i somehow came up that with that capacitor I would need a resistor of 820Ohm to have a cutoff frequency of roughly 195 Hz.

Is that correct? 
Wouldn't that resistor in series lower drastically the input volume to the amplifier?

Comment: [RC filter calculator](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/CRlowkeisan.htm)

Comment: yep, already checked that.. so a 1uF capacitor and a 820 ohm resistor should give 195 hz cutoff frequency.. but what about the volume?

Comment: @sharkyenergy um, what about the volume? That designer tool gives you a bode plot.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, sorry, i am a mechanic and read about RC filters the first time 2 hours ago..  what is a bode plot? the signal going to the amplifier has an amplitude of about 20 mv... what worries me, is that adding the resistor will reduce the tension so much that i cannot hear anything...

Comment: i just tried with a 10uF and a 82 ohm resistor.. according to the simulator it should cut the frequencies above 200 hz.. what it did was lowering drastically the output on all frequencies... as soon as i removed the capacitor it worked normally again..

Comment: The filter impedance depends on if it is at output (like a crossover) or between preamp output & power amp input . Don't put a 820 ohms in series with a 4 ohm speaker.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 its at the input of the amplifier.. between the amplifier and the speaker (8ohm trasducer) there is nothing..

Comment: Then we might assume the driver is < 1Ohm but current limited so X(C=1uF) @ 200Hz = 1/(2pi f C) =   785 Ohms so anything around this value breaks at -3dB so 820 is close .  I'd like a subwoofer mounted under the sofa

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 not sure I understood.. I tried also a 10 uF with a 82 ohm resistor, but didnt work anway.. it did filter, but the output was at least 70% lower than without the capacitor...

Comment: That implies wrong impedances , got links to specs?  probably hard to guess

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 nope, i do not know what chip it is, since it is covered by a cooling fin that i do not want to remove..is there such a big impedance difference between one chip and the other?

Comment: It all depends how it is iused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102640/discussion-between-sharkyenergy-and-tony-stewart-sunnyskyguy-ee75).